# how to increase the size of jenkins pipeline input area?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipe line script : input syntax is,

```
                def newTag = input(
                    id: 'currentTag', message: 'Put the tag for vals here', ok: 'CREATE TAG', 
                        parameters: [
                            string(
                                defaultValue: 'temp', 
                                description: 'Enter carefully for new tag', 
                                name: 'tagName'
                            ),
                        ]
                )
```

While run this, it waits for input with applet.

In doc [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) there is no method to specify the size.

How to increase the size of that input bar ?

Comment: Didn't you try using css?

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please post a screenshot of the applet and add more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use text() instead of string(). The input window can be resized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the size of it, but if you load the 'input' form from the log output or from BlueOcean view, it will look much better for you